# Reset and increment count when column values change

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Hopefully someone can help. I'm using SQL Server 2008, and the compatibility level is 100 and so I am unable to use the lead/lag functionality.

What I'm trying to achieve is to create a sub_task_id based on changes within TRAN_ID, and INTERACTION. All data is sorted by Tran_ID, Task_ID and Interaction_DateTime

Each SUB_TASK will start at 1 for each new TRAN_ID and it remains the same until a new 'Open' interaction is detailed, where it will increment by 1.

I've pre-populated the SUB_TASK with the result I'm looking for. Not sure where to start, any help would be appreciated.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
TRAN_ID | TASK_ID | INTERACTION | INTERACTION_DATETIME    | SUB_TASK_ID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234    | 1       | Open        | 2018-01-04 18:02:18     | 1
1234    | 1       | Close       | 2018-01-04 18:02:27     | 1
2234    | 11      | Open        | 2018-01-03 09:04:33     | 1
2234    | 11      | Close       | 2018-01-03 09:04:50     | 1
2234    | 11      | Open        | 2018-01-04 09:05:29     | 2
2234    | 11      | Edit        | 2018-01-04 09:06:42     | 2
2234    | 11      | Edit        | 2018-01-04 09:07:33     | 2
2234    | 11      | Merge       | 2018-01-04 09:09:21     | 2
2234    | 11      | Close       | 2018-01-04 09:13:50     | 2
2234    | 11      | Open        | 2018-01-05 11:14:34     | 3
2234    | 11      | Edit        | 2018-01-05 11:16:49     | 3
2234    | 11      | Edit        | 2018-01-05 11:21:21     | 3
2234    | 11      | Merge       | 2018-01-05 11:55:33     | 3
2234    | 11      | Close       | 2018-01-05 11:56:12     | 3
3242    | 13      | Open        | 2018-01-03 15:47:22     | 1
3242    | 13      | Close       | 2018-01-03 15:47:59     | 1
3242    | 13      | Open        | 2018-01-19 09:38:09     | 2
3242    | 13      | Edit        | 2018-01-19 09:39:10     | 2
3242    | 13      | Edit        | 2018-01-19 09:42:12     | 2
3242    | 13      | Close       | 2018-01-19 09:46:12     | 2
```

Comment: Why are you unable to use lead/lag?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I see it’s been marked as duplicate, but the linked item uses lead/lag. The database compatibility is set at 100 and I’ve been advised not to change it.

Comment: Okay so I stand corrected, I'm not using 2012. It's 2008, but with SSMS 2012.

Comment: Your desired ordering is not unique. There is nothing that specifies that the many rows with `2234,11,2018-01-03 09:05:20` should be in that order - were some of them supposed to be `2018-01-03 09:06:20`?

Comment: I've amended the table to be a bit more accurate with the dates/times for the interaction times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option for you.

Basically a running total based on TRAN_ID dictated by INTERACTION='Open' since you stated: *"Each SUB_TASK will start at 1 for each new TRAN_ID and it remains the same until a new 'Open' interaction is detailed, where it will increment by 1"*

Challenge is cumulative sums are not supported until SQL Server 2012+ so we'll have to use an outer apply:

Sample temp table with data:

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData 
    (
        [TRAN_ID] INT
      , [TASK_ID] INT
      , [INTERACTION] NVARCHAR(10)
      , [INTERACTION_DATETIME] DATETIME
    );
INSERT INTO #TestData (
                          [TRAN_ID]
                        , [TASK_ID]
                        , [INTERACTION]
                        , [INTERACTION_DATETIME]
                      )
VALUES ( 1234, 1, 'Open', '2018-01-04 18:02:18' )
     , ( 1234, 1, 'Close', '2018-01-04 18:02:27' )
     , ( 2234, 11, 'Open', '2018-01-03 09:04:33' )
     , ( 2234, 11, 'Close', '2018-01-03 09:04:50' )
     , ( 2234, 11, 'Open', '2018-01-04 09:05:29' )
     , ( 2234, 11, 'Edit', '2018-01-04 09:06:42' )
     , ( 2234, 11, 'Edit', '2018-01-04 09:07:33' )
     , ( 2234, 11, 'Merge', '2018-01-04 09:09:21' )
     , ( 2234, 11, 'Close', '2018-01-04 09:13:50' )
     , ( 2234, 11, 'Open', '2018-01-05 11:14:34' )
     , ( 2234, 11, 'Edit', '2018-01-05 11:16:49' )
     , ( 2234, 11, 'Edit', '2018-01-05 11:21:21' )
     , ( 2234, 11, 'Merge', '2018-01-05 11:55:33' )
     , ( 2234, 11, 'Close', '2018-01-05 11:56:12' )
     , ( 3242, 13, 'Open', '2018-01-03 15:47:22' )
     , ( 3242, 13, 'Close', '2018-01-03 15:47:59' )
     , ( 3242, 13, 'Open', '2018-01-19 09:38:09' )
     , ( 3242, 13, 'Edit', '2018-01-19 09:39:10' )
     , ( 3242, 13, 'Edit', '2018-01-19 09:42:12' )
     , ( 3242, 13, 'Close', '2018-01-19 09:46:12' );
```

Then we can use an outer apply.  We'll sum based on INTERACTION equal to 'Open' or not for the TASK_ID where the INTERACTION_DATETIME less than or equal.  This should work in 2008:

```
SELECT      *
FROM        [#TestData] [a]
OUTER APPLY (
                SELECT SUM(   CASE WHEN [b].[INTERACTION] = 'Open' THEN 1
                                   ELSE 0
                              END
                          ) AS [SUB_TASK_ID]
                FROM   [#TestData] [b]
                WHERE  [b].[TRAN_ID] = [a].[TRAN_ID]
                       AND [b].[INTERACTION_DATETIME] <= [a].[INTERACTION_DATETIME]
            ) [s]
ORDER BY [a].[TRAN_ID], [a].[INTERACTION_DATETIME]
```

Giving you your desired results:

```
TRAN_ID     TASK_ID     INTERACTION INTERACTION_DATETIME    SUB_TASK_ID
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------------------- -----------
1234        1           Open        2018-01-04 18:02:18.000 1
1234        1           Close       2018-01-04 18:02:27.000 1
2234        11          Open        2018-01-03 09:04:33.000 1
2234        11          Close       2018-01-03 09:04:50.000 1
2234        11          Open        2018-01-04 09:05:29.000 2
2234        11          Edit        2018-01-04 09:06:42.000 2
2234        11          Edit        2018-01-04 09:07:33.000 2
2234        11          Merge       2018-01-04 09:09:21.000 2
2234        11          Close       2018-01-04 09:13:50.000 2
2234        11          Open        2018-01-05 11:14:34.000 3
2234        11          Edit        2018-01-05 11:16:49.000 3
2234        11          Edit        2018-01-05 11:21:21.000 3
2234        11          Merge       2018-01-05 11:55:33.000 3
2234        11          Close       2018-01-05 11:56:12.000 3
3242        13          Open        2018-01-03 15:47:22.000 1
3242        13          Close       2018-01-03 15:47:59.000 1
3242        13          Open        2018-01-19 09:38:09.000 2
3242        13          Edit        2018-01-19 09:39:10.000 2
3242        13          Edit        2018-01-19 09:42:12.000 2
3242        13          Close       2018-01-19 09:46:12.000 2
```

For 2012+ you can do all of that with the window function. Here's what that would look like just so you have it. A little cleaner and easier:

```
SELECT   *
       , SUM(   CASE WHEN [INTERACTION] = 'Open' THEN 1
                     ELSE 0
                END
            ) OVER ( PARTITION BY [TRAN_ID]
                     ORDER BY [TRAN_ID]
                            , [INTERACTION_DATETIME]
                   ) AS [SUB_TASK_ID]
FROM     [#TestData]
ORDER BY [TRAN_ID]
       , [TASK_ID]
       , [INTERACTION_DATETIME];
```